# Deserialize JSon using the Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
"result" : {
    "id" : "123", 
    "category" : "typeA",
    "value" : {
        "typeAField" : "123"
    }
}


"result" : {
    "id" : "321", 
    "category" : "typeB",
    "value" : {
        "typeBAField1" : "123",
        "typeBAField2" : true
    }
}
```

I want to change the json structure like this to a java object.
The result has an id, category, and value, and the type of object in the value changes depending on the category.

So I created objects like this:
When the value of the category is typeA, I want to use the TypeA.java object, and when the value of the category is typeB, I want to use the TypeB.java object.

```
public class Result { 
  String id;
  String category;
  Values value;
}

public abstract class Values {
    
}

public TypeA extends Values {
    String typeAField;
}

public TypeB extends Values {
    String typeBField1;
    String typeBField2;
}
```

As input as below:

```
"result" : {
    "id" : "123", 
    "category" : "typeA",
    "value" : {
        "typeAField" : "123"
    }
}
```

When text is entered, I want to write code that deserializes it into a Result.java object.

## First method I tried

```
@Data
class Result {
    private String id;
    private String category;
    private Values value;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property = "category")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeA.class, name = "typeA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeB.class, name = "typeB")
})
abstract class Values {}

@Data
class TypeA extends Values {
    private String typeAField;
}

@Data
class TypeB extends Values {
    private String typeBAField1;
    private boolean typeBAField2;
}

String json1 = "{\"id\":\"123\",\"category\":\"typeA\",\"value\":{\"typeAField\":\"123\"}}";
String json2 = "{\"id\":\"321\",\"category\":\"typeB\",\"value\":{\"typeBAField1\":\"123\",\"typeBAField2\":true}}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Result result1 = objectMapper.readValue(json1, Result.class); // error 
Result result2 = objectMapper.readValue(json2, Result.class);
```

**Error details**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'typeAField' as a subtype of `Values`: known type ids = [typeA, typeB] (for POJO property 'value')
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"123","category":"typeA","value":{"typeAField":"123"}}"; line: 1, column: 41] (through reference chain: Result["value"])
```

## The second method I tried

```
@Data
class Result {
    private String id;
    private String category;
    private Values value;

    @JsonSetter("value")
    public void setValue(Map<String, Object> valueMap) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            if (valueMap.containsKey("typeAField")) {
                this.value = objectMapper.convertValue(valueMap, TypeA.class);
            }
            else {
                this.value = objectMapper.convertValue(valueMap, TypeB.class);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Values {}

@Data
class TypeA extends Values {
    private String typeAField;
}

@Data
class TypeB extends Values {
    private String typeBAField1;
    private boolean typeBAField2;
}
```

It works, but the setter part doesn't seem clean.
Is there any better way?
I'm lacking a lot, but I want to get help
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first method, you're using `JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT` which would work if JSON data was like this:

```json
{
    "result": {
        "id": "321",
        "category": "typeB",
        "value": {
            "typeB": {
                "typeBAField1": "123",
                "typeBAField2": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now instead, you may use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` which can only be used for properties, not for types (classes) according to [JavaDocs](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.1.beta/javadocs/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXTERNAL_PROPERTY).

> public static final JsonTypeInfo.As EXTERNAL_PROPERTY
>
> Inclusion mechanism similar to PROPERTY, except that property is included one-level higher in hierarchy, i.e. as sibling property at same level as JSON Object to type. Note that this choice can only be used for properties, not for types (classes). Trying to use it for classes will result in inclusion strategy of basic PROPERTY instead

So you have to annotate value property of Result class using `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY` and remove abstract Values class annotations. Then you can deserialize the JSON data without an error.

```java
@Data
public class Result {
    private String id;
    private String category;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "category")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeA.class, name = "typeA"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TypeB.class, name = "typeB")
    })
    private Values value;
}

abstract class Values {}
```